# Eliminate horizontal scroll which navbar causes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Please consider this simple `Bootstrap` example:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mvquk2t7/)

The navbar cause horizontal scroll how can I elimiate that?

Thanks

Comment: Something is pushing the elements to be more than 100% width of the screen - maybe it's some padding or margins. Anyway, you can control this by adding the following to your code:

`html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
`

Comment: there is a spelling mistake of container-fluid class that you  have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your HTML code with this. You correct your class name spelling **container-fluid**.

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 border-bottom shadow-sm">
        <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal  ">
            My Company
        </h5>
        <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Enterprise</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Support</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Report</a>
        </nav>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#" style="background-color: #007bff; color: white">Hi There</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid margin-top-zero">
        <div class="row">
            <main role="main" class="col-md ml-sm-auto pt-3 px-4">
                <div>
                    Helllooooo
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.row {
  float:left;
}
```